# What was the relationship between Nova and the human soldier?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

When Caesar and the apes first find Nova, she seems to be travelling/hiding with a human soldier, whom the apes are forced to kill after he tries to shoot them.

It's later understood that this soldier is

> a deserter from the Colonel's camp, who most likely ran away with Nova in order to protect her, since the Colonel is murdering all mutes. I base this assumption on the Colonel's own statement, when he claims some soldiers tried running away instead of killing their friends and partners.

This means the soldier is effectively Nova's caretaker. Is he her father? A relative? No particular relation, and he simply chose her to save? I don't remember if they give any hints. If he is her father, it seems strange that Nova comes to trust the apes so quickly -- after all they killed her human protector!